# html form firefox focus

Tags: html, firefox, forms

All right, this one is going to sound very weird and I don't know if any of you have experienced the same problem.

I have a very simple login form (in html) which includes username, password and submit button and works fine on IE but when I run it in Firefox (3.xxx) and click on password textfield, the focus jumps on username and selects the text. What's even more I can easily navigate using the keyboard but not with the mouse click.

Just curious, does anyone else have this problem and perhaps a solution, or is it just me?
Thanks for your time and help!
Uran

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably did something like the following:

```
<label for="username">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
</label>
<label for="username">
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</label>
```

Notice how the second **`label`** is still marked **`for="username"`**. Make sure the **`for`** attribute matches the proper field. Also, when the **`input`** tags are nested in **`label`** you technically don't need to specify a value for **`for`**.

---

The second option is that you did something like the following:

```
<label>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</label>
```

In this case, the focus is given to the first **`input`**. When using **`input`** nested inside a **`label`** tag, makes sure there is only one inside the said **`label`**.

Comment: wow, amazing--- it was the second case and it did fix it, many thanks Andrew

Comment: @Uran: then feel free to mark my answer as accepted. It's that little checkmark below the vote counter.